# Unable to make a factorial function in Python

Tags: python, factorial

**My code**

```
import sys

number=int(sys.argv[1])

if number == 0
    fact=1
else
    fact=number
for (x=1; x<number; x++)
    fact*=x;             // mistake probably here

print fact
```

I get the error

```
File "factorial.py", line 5
    if number == 0
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How can you make a factorial function in Python?**

Comment: While I'm sure you're just trying to learn python, note that this isn't a very efficient way to calculate n!.

Comment: @WaffleMatt: Is the lambda calculus way the best way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's your code, fixed up and working:

```
import sys
number = int(sys.argv[1])
fact = 1
for x in range(1, number+1):
    fact *= x

print fact
```

(Factorial zero is one, for anyone who didn't know - I had to look it up. 8-)

You need colons after `if`, `else`, `for`, etc., and the way `for` works in Python is different from C.

Answer (score 12):

The line that your error is on should read

```
if number == 0:
```

Note the colon on the end.

Additionally, you would need to add the same colon after the else and the for. The colons work similarly to {} in other languages.

Finally, thats not how for loops work in Python. The code you want to use that list would be

```
for x in range(1,number):
```

Which would have the same effect of what you wrote, if you put that in a C style language.

EDIT: Oops, the for loop I gave was wrong, it would have included 0. I updated the code to correct this.

Answer (score 9):

I understand that you are probably trying to implement this yourself for educational reasons.

However, if not, I recommend using the `math` modules built-in factorial function (note: requires python 2.6 or higher):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial(5)
120
```

This module is written in C, and as such, it'll be much much faster than writing it in python.  (although, if you aren't computing large factorials, it won't really be too slow either way).

Answer (score 3):

The reason Mark Rushakoff's fact(n) function was so much more efficient was that he missed-off the reduce() function.  Thus it never actually did the calculation.

Corrected it reads (and I get):

```
import operator, timeit, math
#
def fact1(n):  return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,  range(1,n+1),1)
def fact1x(n): return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, xrange(1,n+1),1)
def fact2(n):  return reduce(operator.mul   ,  range(1,n+1),1)
def fact2x(n): return reduce(operator.mul   , xrange(1,n+1),1)
#
def factorialtimer():
    for myfunc in [ "fact1", "fact1x", "fact2", "fact2x" ]:
        mytimer = timeit.Timer(myfunc+"(1500)", "from __main__ import "+myfunc)
        print("{0:15} : {1:2.6f}".format(myfunc, mytimer.timeit(number=1000)))

    mytimer = timeit.Timer("factorial(1500)", "from math import factorial")
    print("{0:15} : {1:2.6f}".format("math.factorial", mytimer.timeit(number=1000)))
```

Resulting output for 1500!, 1000x:

```
fact1           : 3.537624
fact1x          : 4.448408
fact2           : 4.390820
fact2x          : 4.333070
math.factorial  : 4.091470
```

And yes, I have checked they all yield the same value!
I Can't understand why the lambda xrange is so much worse than the lambda range.  Hmmm.
Version: 
PythonWin 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.

Hmm... on re-running it I get something more believable

```
fact1           : 7.771696
fact1x          : 7.799568
fact2           : 7.056820
fact2x          : 7.247851
math.factorial  : 6.875827
```

And on Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01) [GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin:

```
fact1           : 6.547000
fact1x          : 6.411000
fact2           : 6.068000
fact2x          : 6.246000
math.factorial  : 6.276000
```

All in the noise really, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional factorial, which you almost asked for:

```
>>> def fact(n): return reduce (lambda x,y: x*y, range(1,n+1))
... 
>>> fact(5)
120
```

It doesn't work for fact(0), but you can worry about that outside the scope of `fact` :)

---

Masi has asked whether the functional style is more efficient than Richie's implementation.  According to my quick benchmark (and to my surprise!) yes, mine is faster.  But there's a couple things we can do to change.

First, we can substitute `lambda x,y: x*y` with `operator.mul` as suggested in another comment.  Python's `lambda` operator comes with a not-insignificant overhead.  Second, we can substitute `xrange` for `range`.  `xrange` should work in linear space, returning numbers as necessary, while `range` creates the whole list all at once.  (Note then, that you almost certainly must use `xrange` for an excessively large range of numbers)

So the new definition becomes:

```
>>> import operator
>>> def fact2(n): return reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1,n+1))
... 
>>> fact2(5)
120
```

To my surprise, this actually resulted in slower performance.  Here's the Q&D benchmarks:

```
>>> def fact(n): return (lambda x,y: x*y, range(1,n+1))
... 
>>> t1 = Timer("fact(500)", "from __main__ import fact")
>>> print t1.timeit(number = 500)
0.00656795501709

>>> def fact2(n): return reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1,n+1))
...
>>> t2 = Timer("fact2(500)", "from __main__ import fact2")
>>> print t2.timeit(number = 500)
0.35856294632

>>> def fact3(n): return reduce(operator.mul, range(1,n+1))
... 
>>> t3 = Timer("fact3(500)", "from __main__ import fact3")
>>> print t3.timeit(number = 500)
0.354646205902

>>> def fact4(n): return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, xrange(1,n+1))
... 
>>> t4 = Timer("fact4(500)", "from __main__ import fact4")
>>> print t4.timeit(number = 500)
0.479015111923

>>> def fact5(n):
...     x = 1
...     for i in range(1, n+1):
...             x *= i
...     return x
... 
>>> t5 = Timer("fact5(500)", "from __main__ import fact5")
>>> print t5.timeit(number = 500)
0.388549804688
```

Here's my Python version in case anyone wants to cross-check my results:

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
```

Comment: "lambda x,y: x*y" can be spelled "operator.mul" (but explicit is better than implicit 8-)

Comment: @Mark: Is your way more efficient than Richie's code? % Can you calculate, for instance, 20000000! with your code exactly?

Comment: @Mark: Thank you for your edit! --- It seems that we cannot calculate 20000000000! in Sun's lifetime.

Comment: @Masi: doing the factorial of 20000000 isn't likely to be fast at all using a naive algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

really, the simplest option would be:

```
def factorial(n):
    x = n
    for j in range(1, n):
        x = j*x
    return x
```

yes, somehow, it works.

How could you not think of this?  I don't know.

A `for` loop and a multiplier, really simplicity is the best way to go, right?

EDIT: Oh, wait, we're working for the most cpu-efficeint way?  ohhhh.....

Answer (score 0):

My guess, it may be helps

```py
def recursive_fact(x :int)->int:
    if x == 0:
        yield 1
    yield x * next(recursive_fact(x-1))
```

and result

```py
print(list(recursive_fact(6)))
```